# R regex to list files that do not begin with eg `AA` or `BB`

Tags: r, regex, import, stringr, readr

Here's the reprex we'll need to create in our working directory:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(readxl)
write.xlsx(list(iris), "AA-excel-file.xlsx")
write.xlsx(list(iris), "BB-excel-file.xlsx")
write.xlsx(list(iris), "CC-excel-file.xlsx")
write.xlsx(list(iris), "DD-excel-file.xlsx")
write.xlsx(list(iris), "EE-excel-file.xlsx")
```

And my working directory looks something like this:

```
C:
├── my-R-working-directory/
    ├── AA-excel-file.xlsx
    ├── BB-excel-file.xlsx
    ├── CC-excel-file.xlsx
    ├── DD-excel-file.xlsx
    └── EE-excel-file.xlsx
```

I've crafted a regular expression [(demo here)](https://regex101.com/r/HgRLBG/1) that "selects" any file that does not begin with either `AA` or `BB`:

```
^(?!AA|BB)\w+$
```

I want to use this regex with base R `list.files()` to list all files that do not begin with either `AA` or `BB`. Here's my attempt:

```
list.files("path/of/folder", pattern = "\\^(?!AA|BB)\w+$.xlsx$", full.names = TRUE)
#> Error: '\w' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\\^(?!AA|BB)\w"
#> Error: unexpected ')' in "           full.names = TRUE)"
```

I think my pattern argument is slightly off. This similar command does work fine, but doesn't exclude the `AA` and `BB` files:

```
list.files("path/of/folder", pattern = "\\.xlsx$", full.names = TRUE)
```

How do I properly write the `pattern` argument to exclude any files that start with `AA` or `BB`? And if you have the capability can you correct my regular expression? The regex only seems to work with "letters or numbers" characters. Any white space, dashes, dots, etc. break the regex [(see demo)](https://regex101.com/r/HgRLBG/1).

Comment: Couldn't you just do `grep("^(AA|BB).*", list.files("path/of/folder", pattern = "\\.xlsx$"), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)` ?

Comment: @Allan Cameron that almost works. There seems to be two issues _(1)_ I only want to include `*.xlsx` files and this doesn't seem to accomplish that and _(2)_ it also does not exclude directories (folders).

Comment: Jason - see my formal answer. This is run in my R home directory, which has multiple other files and directories. It's maybe modified a bit from my original suggestion.

Comment: @Allan Cameron Yup, your formal answer appears to have solved it. Thanks. I'll give the customary 24 hour period to let others a chance to solve as well.

Comment: I'm pleased that worked Jason. I'd be interested to see if there's a solution just using `pattern`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pattern` to get all `xlsx` files then inverse `grep` those starting with `AA` or `BB`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(readxl)

write.xlsx(list(iris), "AA-excel-file.xlsx")
write.xlsx(list(iris), "BB-excel-file.xlsx")
write.xlsx(list(iris), "CC-excel-file.xlsx")
write.xlsx(list(iris), "DD-excel-file.xlsx")
write.xlsx(list(iris), "EE-excel-file.xlsx")

grep("^(AA|BB).*", list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx$"), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#> [1] "CC-excel-file.xlsx" "DD-excel-file.xlsx" "EE-excel-file.xlsx"
```